# Postgres, a fresh install of Mavericks and rails. Cannot fix this database connection issue...

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, osx-mavericks

There are a few other issues similar to this on stack overflow however they don't fix it and are not related to Mavericks, I think this is a Mavericks specific issue.

I have a fresh install of Mavericks and I have brew installed postgres however I’m getting a strange error when running my rails app:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Postgres is up and running, I can view the whole database in the command line. Rails console also throws this error.

There is a /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock file that looks similar t othe one this is looking for.

There is no .s.PGSQL.5432 file in the directory it’s looking for.

In my database.yml in rails I have the host set as localhost.

Can anyone tell me what this error is about and how to fix it please.

Comment: The error message mentioning the Unix domain socket contradicts the host being set to `localhost` in database.yml. And you are not the first poster on S.O. who reports this apparent discrepancy since Maverick. If you set the host to a dummy name like `does-not-exist` do you still get the same error message?

Comment: @DanielVérité this caused an 'could not translate host name "does-not-exist" to address' error

Comment: Which is the expected error, and proves that it takes into account the host. So the question is: why when setting it to `localhost`, it tries to use a Unix domain socket instead of just doing what it's told? Is is trying to outsmart the user? Anyway, the normal fix would be to set the host to `/tmp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client (psql or whatever) is configured to look for unix sockets in /var/run but your server is using /tmp. This suggests that your psql is an old version rather than whatever you compiled - check your PATH.

You can use the path as a hostname:

```
psql -h /tmp -p 5432 ...
```

Comment: @Smickie - Don't believe you. The error message should reflect the path specified via `-h`. Try `-h /blahblah` an see what that shows.

Comment: I took a screen shot... it did throw that error :/ http://i.imgur.com/H4ZTvc7.png

Comment: No - that's the error you would expect with a "/tmp" path rather than the "/var/pgsql_socket/..." you said you were getting originally. Check if that socket is still there + that the server is still running.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to connect from another machine via psql (i.e., you have modified pg_hba.conf to allow this), try changing local host to the IP.